# Klang vs. Schall

Tags: difference

My understanding is that *Klang* and *Schall* both mean *sound* but in different contexts. I could piece this together if I could figure out which contexts, but it appears that they are interchangeable?

Further complicating the matter is that the German Wikipedia article on *Klang* seems similar to the English article on *sound,* but the *other languages* bar from the English article links to *Schall,* which appears to be strictly scientific.

Which one is used where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Klang**

the acoustic impression of something; the way something sounds

> *Klang des Klaviers*, *schöner Klang*, *durchdringender Klang*, *schriller Klang*, *warmer Klang einer Stimme*, *fröhliche Klänge des Stadtorchesters*

**Schall**

an undulated oscillation propagating in a medium.

> *Schallgeschwindigkeit, Schalldämpfung, Schallwelle*

===

There are also some additional meanings, used metaphorically or in literature (both fiction and technical), for example:

> Glockenschall (*bell sound*)
>
> Schall und Rauch (*hollow words*)
>
> Vierklang (*tetrad*)

Comment: So a sound in general is Schall?

Comment: @kelario I'd rather say it's *Klang* in general and *Schall* in a scientific context.

Comment: @kelario As a general term I'd use _Geräusch_.

Comment: @PerlDog Not sure, if *Geräusch* is not more like *noise*. I've never heard someone saying *Klaviergeräusch* for *piano sound*.

Comment: True, but consider clapping your hands. That would be a Geräusch. It's more like _noise_, agreed.

Comment: Agreed. However, the OP asked for the difference between *Klang* and *Schall*, so I assumed he has no problem with the word *Geräusch*. Don't know, if the assumption was correct - the word *Geräusch* is a very important one, but still not a generic term - neither for *Klang* nor for *Schall* - just different meaning.

Comment: *"Musik wird störend oft empfunden, weil stets sie mit Geräusch verbunden"* - Wilhelm Busch

Comment: @tofro This is a nice quote, but I find it confusing as an example for this particular discussion. Saying, music is a *Geräusch* works **pejoratively** - because music is normally not just a noise. *Geräusch* would be something like cars passing by, clapping hands, someone knocking on the door etc.

Comment: @tofro lol, now translate _that_ into English. :-)

Comment: *Music is often disturbing, because it is always a sort of noise*

Comment: _Music often is disturbing // because it is a noisy serving._ (sorry, this is getting off-topic, but I couldn't resist)

Answer (score 9):

I hope its ok when I answer in German:

### Schall

Schall ist ein physikalisches Phänomen. Der Begriff gehört also zur wissenschaftlichen Disziplin *Physik*. Dabei geht es um die Ausbreitung von mechanischen Schwingungen durch ein Medium. Schall wird durch mechanische Ereignisse erzeugt, pflanzt sich durch ein Medium fort und bringt dann an einer anderen Stelle andere Gegenstände zum Schwingen.

Von Schall spricht man auch dann, wenn die Schwingungen nicht geeignet sind, vom menschlichen Gehör wahrgenommen zu werden. Schwingungen, deren Frequenzen zu groß für das menschliche Gehör sind, bezeichnet man als Ultraschall. Sind die Frequenzen zu tief, spricht man von Infraschall.

---

Die folgenden Begriffe kommen nur zur Anwendung, wenn der Schall von Menschen wahrgenommen werden kann:

### Geräusch, Klang, Ton

Das sind drei Begriffe, die in der Wahrnehmungslehre und in der Musik beheimatet sind, aber durchaus auch in die Physik hineinreichen.

**Ton**

Ein Ton ist eine Schwingung, die theoretisch unendlich lang andauert, eine unveränderliche Lautstärke (Amplitude) hat und nur in einer einzigen Frequenz stattfindet. Ein Ton hört sich z. B. so an: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GvDyPzpa8HY

**Klang**

Ein Klang ist eine Kombination von mehreren Tönen mit unterschiedlichen Frequenzen. Ein Klang kann durch Fourieranalyse in seine Bestandteile, die einzelnen Töne, aufgespalten werden. Auch ein Klang hat theoretisch eine unendlich lange Dauer und eine unveränderliche Lautstärke. Da man aber in der Musik keine Instrumente hat, die diese Bedingung erfüllen, zählt man auch solche akustischen Ereignisse zu den Klängen, die zwar ihre Lautstärke im Lauf der Zeit ändern, bei denen sich die Frequenzen der einzelnen Töne aber trotzdem nicht ändern.

Damit ein akustisches Ereignis noch als Klang klassifiziert werden kann, darf die Anzahl der darin enthaltenen Töne nicht zu groß sein. Das heißt, dass das Frequenzspektrum eines Klanges aus einzelnen Linien besteht. Es darf darin kein Kontinuum geben. Wenn das Spektrum zusätzlich zu einem Frequenz-Kontinuum auch scharfe Linien enthält, ist das akustische Ereignis wegen des Kontinuums trotzdem als Geräusch (siehe unten) und nicht als Klang einzustufen.

Wenn man eine Taste eines Klaviers betätigt, ertönt ein Klang. Drückt man mehrere Tasten zugleich, ertönt ebenfalls ein Klang (aber ein anderer). Auch das Streichen oder Zupfen einer Geigensaite erzeugt einen Klang, und auch ein Sänger erzeugt beim Singen von Vokalen Klänge.

**Geräusch**

Jedes akustische Ereignis, das weder ein Ton noch ein Klang ist, ist ein Geräusch. Der Schall, der von einem Automotor ausgeht, ist ein Geräusch; denn wenn man dieses akustische Ereignis einer Fourieranalyse unterzieht, sieht man im Frequenzspektrum eine Kurve (mit Zacken, aber eben eine Kurve) und keine einzelnen scharfen Linien.

Comment: Wie gewohnt eine tolle Antwort, aber ob der OP die *auf deutsch* beschriebene Fourier-Analyse und Frequenzspektren versteht?

Comment: Ich bin mir auch nicht ganz sicher, ob eine physikalische Analyse von "Klang" geeignet ist, den grundsätzlichen Unterschied zwischen *Klang* und *Schall* herauszuarbeiten. Für mich ist das eher kontraproduktiv.

Comment: @BarthZalewski: Ich kann nicht gut genug Englisch, um diesen Text in dieser Sprache zu schreiben. Es steht ja jedem, der gut genug Englisch spricht, frei, meine Antwort zu editieren und eine englische Übersetzung hinzuzufügen. (Bitte ohne den deutschen Text zu löschen!)

Comment: So oder so, die Antwort bleibt auch für künftige Googler sicherlich hilfreich.

Answer (score 6):

*Schall* is in contemporary German reserved for describing the physical aspects of sound in scientifical context ("Schallgeschwindigkeit").

*Klang* is the effect of "Schall" on the human ears - It mostly describes aspects of sound related to human perception ("Klangerlebnis").

As you might see from the above, the words are generally **not** interchangeable.

In old texts or poetry, you might find *Schall* and *Klang* used as close synonyms like in

> Hört der Glocken hellen Schall

This is, however, outdated usage.

Comment: I cannot agree with *Klang is the effect of "Schall" on the human ears*, as the same definition applies to *Geräusch*.

Comment: I'm not saying "effect on ears" - I'm saying perception. How else would you explain "Schon am Klang seiner Stimme am Telefon erkannte sie, das etwas passiert sein musste"

Comment: Ok, agreed - misunderstood